# \allowdisplaybreaks does not work anymore if empheq is loaded

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, empheq

I'm using the package `mathtools` using the option `showonlyrefs`. This works fine, however some equation numbers are skipped. If I understood the manual correctly I need to load `empheq` to fix this. This works!

The problem now is that without `empheq` `\allowdisplaybreaks` works fine, but the equation numbering goes wrong, but with `empheq` the `\allowdisplaybreaks` seems to stop working (this is a command from `amsmath`).

Is this a common problem? I can't seem to find anything about it. How can I solve this?

**Edit:** I have finally found the time to make a MWE. See below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, leqno, final, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload, ntheorem]{empheq}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]
\begin{align}
  A &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A\\
  &= A
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Drop the `overload` option for the [empheq](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package. You then can't use the short form for emphasized equations. See Section 2.2.2 of the package manual.

Comment: Thanks. That does fix a lot. However, now for some reason `\tag[$\ast$]` stopped working. Could this be connected to this?

Comment: Shouldn't that read `\tag{$\ast$}`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I have no problem with manual tagging.

Comment: It is a strange thing, sometimes `\tag{$\ast$}` doesn't work, sometimes it does and when it doesn't `\tag{*}` does work. I'll try to figure out.

Comment: This might be stuff for a new question if you manage to prepare a minimal example. According to your description this behaviour seems to be random.

Comment: Sorry. I have missed something. This indeed fixes one problem but it messes up the other problem. Now `mathtools` skips some equation numbers. The fix in the `mathtools` manual is to add `\usepackage[overload, ntheorem]{empheq}` to the code!